# GA4 Google Analytics. gtag.js sends a request with a delay of a few seconds, not instantly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics

The problem is that a request to Google `https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?` is not sent immediately, but after 3-4 seconds. I looked for a solution in the official documentation from Google, but did not find it. I want this request to be sent immediately.

I added a script to the head tag as stated in the documentation from Google.

```js
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script
  async
  src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=MY_KEY"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []
  function gtag() {
    dataLayer.push(arguments)
  }
  gtag('js', new Date())
  gtag('config', 'MY_KEY', {send_page_view: false})
</script>
```

My app is built on React version `^18.2.0` and using `react-router` and `react-router-dom`. I use `useEffect` to send event.

```js
const location = useLocation()

useEffect(() => {
  window.gtag('event', 'page_view', {
    page_location: window.location.href,
    page_path: location.pathname + location.search + location.hash,
    page_search: location.search,
    page_hash: location.hash,
  })
}, [location.pathname])
```

Comment: Is 3 to 4 seconds not "immediate" enough for you? AFAIK collecting analytics tends to be a bit asynchronous. It might just be the case that GA4 is batching events so it's not generating network traffic for each and every little event you may be collecting data on.

Comment: GA4 is its faster than ua was.   I would suggest you learn to live with this reasonable delay in a service you are probably getting for free

Answer (score 0):

What you're experiencing is the new feature of gtag.js. The GA4 tracking library.

Here's more about it from [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688?hl=en):

> Event grouping Most of the events that users trigger on your website
> or app are not sent one at a time. Instead, most events are grouped
> together (or batched).
>
> However, events are not batched in the following circumstances:
>
> Conversion events are transmitted immediately, although they may be
> part of a batch Containers loaded in debug mode never batch events to
> provide you with realtime data Events that are temporarily stored by
> your device are sent when a user leaves a page In browser environments
> that don't support the sendBeacon API, all events are sent immediately

I'm trying to find a way to stop the library from batching events, but I don't see anything documented as of yet. Will update this if I find a way that wouldn't involve rewriting the library.

In vast majority of cases, nobody cares about the few seconds delay in when the event is sent, given that the batched events are meant to have timestamps of when they were triggered rather than when the batch was sent.

Note that batching only works when the sendBeacon api is available. This is mostly to avoid the request/data loss on window unload. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon).